# How to remove li dynamic tag?

Tags: javascript, tags, html-lists

it's my first question..i am Korean, so am not good at Enlish. i am experiencing a thrill. plz answer my question TT

i'm using Spring framework, and studying file-upload and download.

```
var added="<li data-filename="+data+"><img src='/displayFile?fileName="+data+"'></li>";

         $("#uploaded").append(added);
```

i used for-statement. so i made several li tag.. i wanna remove one li tag
.. but it is hard for me to remove it..

i tried, searched.. but i failed..

i used this statement

```
 $("#uploaded").on("click","li", function(event){

       var delfile=$(this).attr("data-filename");  
       alert(delfile+"를 삭제하겠습니다.");
       $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/deleteFile',
              data: {fileName:delfile},
              dataType:'text',

              success: function(data){
                if(data=='deleted'){

                    alert("deleted");

                    //$('#uploaded li:has(img[src="/displayFile?fileName="+delfile])').remove();
                    $(this).remove();
                }   
              } //success부분 끝부분
        }); //ajax부분 끝부분
   }); //li부분 끝부분
```

i used this statement to remove one li tag.. but it doesn't work

```
$(this).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` points to the `#uploaded` element. You have to then, find the `li` tag you want to remove.

Try,

`$(this).find('li').remove();` // this will remove all `li` tags

`$(this).find('li:first').remove();` // this will remove the first `li` tag